# WordPress country list gone

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, country

after installing this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-china-checkout/, all my country list gone and only left China.

I try to deactive this plugin at still don't get back other country list.

How can I fix this without install new WordPress?

[image: See the image]

Comment: do you have any backup?

Comment: no, I forget to backup

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have installed the WC China Checkout Plugin, Selling location(s) option has change to only specific country and country will set as China. When you deactivated the plugin, the option was not changed. So we manually have to change that options in WP Backend.

**Follow the following steps:**

In wordpress backend, go to Woocommerce->Settings and in this page `Selling location(s)` under `General options` title.

In Selling location(s), change the dropdown as `Sell to all countries`